# Codeception WebDriver executeInSelenium issue (wrong instance given)

Tags: selenium, codeception, remotewebdriver

I'm trying to switch to a new opened window in codeception using WebDriver.
I used the code from manual so:

```
    $I->executeInSelenium(function (\Webdriver\Session $webdriver) {
        $handles=$webdriver->window_handles();
        $last_window = end($handles);
        $webdriver->focusWindow($last_window);
    });
```

Unfortunately the webdriver for some reason is not instance of Webdriver\Session but RemoteDriver

```
  [ErrorException] Argument 1 passed to
  Codeception\Module\magicguyHelper::Codeception\Module\{closure}()
  must be an instance of WebDriver\Session, instance of RemoteWebDriver given,
  called in 
  phar:///tester/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Module/WebDriver.php
  on line 1038 and defined
```

Anyone understand why this issue appeared ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `switchTo()` instead of `focusWindow()` and also `WebDriver` as a parameter (not `WebDriver\Session`):

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\Webdriver $webdriver) {
    $handles=$webdriver->getWindowHandles();
    $last_window = end($handles);
    $webdriver->switchTo()->window($last_window);
});
```